# Copy uploaded image to another folder

Tags: php, upload, copy

I am having a small issue that would love to get some assistance on, I have a image upload that I am building and would like to move the file to a folder **image** and copy it to a folder **image_thumb** also. I am using arrays with keys but when I try to add the copy() function it gives an error saying that it failed to open stream.

It manages to upload the image to **image** folder, but not the other one, could someone tell me what I did wrong in the **copy($key, "image_thumbnail/" . $_FILES['images']['name'][$i]);** function.

Thank you for the awesome upcoming assistance :)

Here is my code

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['addpart'])) {

    $image = $_FILES['images']['tmp_name'];
    $i     = 0;
    foreach ($image as $key) {
        move_uploaded_file($key, "image/" . $_FILES['images']['name'][$i]);
        copy($key, "image_thumbnail/" . $_FILES['images']['name'][$i]);
        $i++;
    }
    echo 'Uploaded';
    echo '<hr>';

}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do move_uploaded file it is removing tmp file from $_FILES['images']['tmp_name'].

You have to make copy like this:

```
move_uploaded_file($key, "image/" . $_FILES['images']['name'][$i]);
copy($_FILES['images']['name'][$i], "image_thumbnail/" . $_FILES['images']['name'][$i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
copy($key, "image_thumbnail/" . $_FILES['images']['name'][$i]);
```

use this

```
copy("image/" . $_FILES['images']['name'][$i], "image_thumbnail/" . $_FILES['images']['name'][$i]);
```